# Close or hide iframe

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe

This is my iframe, it is a google form, which means I cannot edit that.I need this iframe to close or hide by any means i.e., a button, a popup window button or maybe without any button.
$gLink is a google form Link, carried by a php sesssion variable.

```
<iframe name="target" id="target" width="320" height="187" frameborder="0" src="<?php echo 
htmlspecialchars($gLink); ?>"></iframe>
```

I had tried this, but it did not work.

```
var iframe=document.getElementById("target");
iframe.parent.removeChild(iframe);
```

This is another code I tried, which also did not work.

```
<script>
    function myFunction{
        var closeIFrame= function(event)
        {
        if (!event || event.data != "FeedbackWidgetClose")
            return;
        fifToggle();
        }

        window.addEventListener("message", closeIFrame, false); 
    }
</script>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Click me</button>
```

Comment: Your first code should work if the iframe exists when that code is executed. My guess is that you run that too early. Maybe you placed it in the `<head>` section without waiting for the document to be loaded. Try putting your `<script>` tag right before the closing `</body>` tag

Answer (score 0):

There is no `parent`. You should use `parentElement`:

```
iframe.parentElement.removeChild(iframe);
```

A tip for future debugging: open up the [web console](https://balsamiq.com/support/faqs/browserconsole/) in your browser so you can detect any errors that occur as your interacting with your page.

Also, your function `myFunction` should be defined like this (its missing the brackets):

```
function myFunction() {
```